# Does Solr try to read stored fields for every search request?

Tags: solr, lucene

I mean in ES, even a client specified only id fields to retrieve, it tries to lookup stored fields after acquired document ids for it's own good.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/fetch/FetchPhase.java#L109

I just wonder the case is same in Solr.

Does it involve any kind of reading stored fields even a client asked it to retrieve only id field of documents that match the given query?

The reason for asking this is that, reading a stored field basically is a decompression which requires a lot of computation costs.

It would be appreciated if anyone could tell this, or could hint me a name of class to digging into.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Solr only reads those fields that you specify in the query.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then can you please give me any clues?
I need very specific evidences back my theory that, as you mentioned, it read only specified fields